# Adding an ifelse statement inside purrrs map function and apply some tidyverse functions

Tags: r, purrr

I have some lists which look like:

```
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
                         title                        company                     date_range                       location 
            "Founder | Co-CEO"                  "someCompany" "ene. de 2018 \023 actualidad"                       "Europe" 
                   description                 li_company_url 
          "some description 1"       "https://www.google.com" 

[[2]][[2]]
                         title                        company                     date_range                       location 
               "Another title"                 "someCompany2" "ene. de 2019 \023 actualidad"                          "USA" 
                   description                 li_company_url 
         "Another Description"        "https://www.yahoo.com" 

[[2]][[3]]
                          title                         company                      date_range                        location 
              "Another title 3"             "Another company 3" "sept. de 2018 \023 actualidad"                        "Europe" 
                    description                  li_company_url 
        "Another description 3" "https://www.stackexchange.com"
```

One is a populated list and the other is a `NULL`. I can run the following code:

```
map(myLists2, function(x){
  if(length(x) > 0){
    print("this list is bigger than 0")
  } else{
    print("this list is less than 0")
  }
})
```

Which gives me an output:

```
[1] "this list is less than 0"
[1] "this list is bigger than 0"
[[1]]
[1] "this list is less than 0"

[[2]]
[1] "this list is bigger than 0"
```

I want to apply some `tidyverse` functions to the data. Since I have some lists which are `NULL` I obtain some errors. The code I want to run is the following:

```
myLists2[[2]] %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(c(paste("jobPosition", seq_along(1:ncol(.)), sep = ""))) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("tag") %>% 
  mutate(
    across(everything(), ~as.character(.x)),
    across(everything(), ~replace_na(.x, 0))
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("jobPosition")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "tag", values_from = "value")
```

Which gives me a `tibble`:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  name         title            company          date_range                      location description          li_company_url             
  <chr>        <chr>            <chr>            <chr>                           <chr>    <chr>                <chr>                      
1 jobPosition1 Founder | Co-CEO someCompany      "ene. de 2018 \u0013 actualida~ Europe   some description 1   https://www.google.com     
2 jobPosition2 Another title    someCompany2     "ene. de 2019 \u0013 actualida~ USA      Another Description  https://www.yahoo.com      
3 jobPosition3 Another title 3  Another company~ "sept. de 2018 \u0013 actualid~ Europe   Another description~ https://www.stackexchange.~
```

However this only works for the second list since it is populated - when I replace `myLists2[[2]]` with `myLists2[[1]]` I obtain an error due to the `setNames()` function.

> Error in names(object) <- nm :    'names' attribute [2] must be the
> same length as the vector [0]

My question is, how can I apply the `tidyverse` code to the `ifelse` statement such that it only processes the populated lists (and therefore does not retrun an error)?

Data:

```
myLists2 <- list(NULL, list(c(title = "Founder | Co-CEO", company = "someCompany", 
date_range = "ene. de 2018 \023 actualidad", location = "Europe", 
description = "some description 1", li_company_url = "https://www.google.com"
), c(title = "Another title", company = "someCompany2", date_range = "ene. de 2019 \023 actualidad", 
location = "USA", description = "Another Description", li_company_url = "https://www.yahoo.com"
), c(title = "Another title 3", company = "Another company 3", 
date_range = "sept. de 2018 \023 actualidad", location = "Europe", 
description = "Another description 3", li_company_url = "https://www.stackexchange.com"
)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `tidyverse` you can try `map_if` :

```
library(tidyverse)
map_if(myLists2, Negate(is.null), expand_list)

#[[1]]
#NULL

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#  name         title           company          date_range                     location description         li_company_url             
#  <chr>        <chr>           <chr>            <chr>                          <chr>    <chr>               <chr>                      
#1 jobPosition1 Founder | Co-C… someCompany      "ene. de 2018 \u0013 actualid… Europe   some description 1  https://www.google.com     
#2 jobPosition2 Another title   someCompany2     "ene. de 2019 \u0013 actualid… USA      Another Description https://www.yahoo.com      
#3 jobPosition3 Another title 3 Another company… "sept. de 2018 \u0013 actuali… Europe   Another descriptio… https://www.stackexchange.…
```

where `expand_list` is your function.

```
expand_list <- function(x) {
x %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(c(paste("jobPosition", seq_along(1:ncol(.)), sep = ""))) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("tag") %>% 
  mutate(
    across(everything(), ~as.character(.x)),
    across(everything(), ~replace_na(.x, 0))
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("jobPosition")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "tag", values_from = "value")
}
```